# java Coding , Dijkastra Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm

**Question Link**
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/number-of-ways-to-arrive-at-destination/1

```
class Pair {
    int first;
    int second;
    public Pair(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
class Solution {

    static int countPaths(int n, List < List < Integer >> roads) {
        
        // Creating an adjacency list for the given graph.
        ArrayList < ArrayList < Pair >> adj = new ArrayList < > ();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            adj.add(new ArrayList < > ());
        }
        int m = roads.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            adj.get(roads.get(i).get(0)).add(new Pair(roads.get(i).get(1), roads.get(i).get(2)));
            adj.get(roads.get(i).get(1)).add(new Pair(roads.get(i).get(0), roads.get(i).get(2)));
        }

        // Defining a priority queue (min heap). 
        PriorityQueue < Pair > pq = new PriorityQueue < Pair > ((x, y) -> x.first - y.first);

        // Initializing the dist array and the ways array
        // along with their first indices.
        int[] dist = new int[n];
        int[] ways = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dist[i] = (int) 1e9;
            ways[i] = 0;
        }
        dist[0] = 0;
        ways[0] = 1;
        pq.add(new Pair(0, 0));

        // Define modulo value
        int mod = (int)(1e9 + 7);

        // Iterate through the graph with the help of priority queue
        // just as we do in Dijkstra's Algorithm.
        while (pq.size() != 0) {
            int dis = pq.peek().first;
            int node = pq.peek().second;
            pq.remove();

            for (Pair it : adj.get(node)) {
                int adjNode = it.first;
                int edW = it.second;

                // This ‘if’ condition signifies that this is the first
                // time we’re coming with this short distance, so we push
                // in PQ and keep the no. of ways the same.
                if (dis + edW < dist[adjNode]) {
                    dist[adjNode] = dis + edW;
                    pq.add(new Pair(dis + edW, adjNode));
                    ways[adjNode] = ways[node];
                } 

                    // If we again encounter a node with the same short distance
                    // as before, we simply increment the no. of ways.
                    else if (dis + edW == dist[adjNode]) {
                    ways[adjNode] = (ways[adjNode] + ways[node]) % mod;
                }
            }
        }
        // Finally, we return the no. of ways to reach
        // (n-1)th node modulo 10^9+7.
        return ways[n - 1] % mod;
    }
}
```

This is my code it is using modified DIJKASTRA algo and it is passing 12 testcases out of 16
but Not working for this testcase.
For Input:
6 8
0 1 1000000000
0 3 1000000000
1 3 1000000000
1 2 1000000000
1 5 1000000000
3 4 1000000000
4 5 1000000000
2 5 1000000000
Your Output:
0
Expected Output:
1

If we observe the edge weight is 1e9 of all edges and i don't know what changes to make.

I tried changing some condtions that are already there but it was stucking at previous testcases so i didn't updated anything.

expecting to pass this edge case.

Comment: You are initializing the distances to 1e9 and it fails on a testcase where edge weights are one billion. I wonder if there is a connection. Maybe you should try a larger "infinite" value.